# UILabel.center is 0? how is that possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uikit, uilabel

I'm trying to get the CGPoint from the center property of some UILabels (which is part of an outlet collection). Now, when i do:

```
for (UILabel *label in labelCollection) {
      NSLog(@"%f", label.center.x);
}
```

It simply returns 0, same with the center.y? how come? i need those coordinates hehe :)

thanks on advance

//EDIT
Uploaded a picture: the labels with "a" "b" "c" "d" is the labels i'm talking about. i tried changing the text.property in the code and that works well, but it just wont give me the coordinates it's on.
[image: example]

Comment: Are the labels being displayed on the screen when you run that loop?

Comment: Yes, they are being displayed on the screen.

Comment: I'd try logging their frame values to see if there was anything suspicious.  (NSStringFromRect(label.frame))

Comment: Okay something really weird is going on, i tried doing         NSLog(@"%f, %f", label.frame.size.height, label.frame.size.width);
        NSLog(@"%f, %f", label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y); and it ALL returns 0

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that the label objects in that collection are not the same objects on your screen.  If you change each label's text in that loop, does it change the display?

Comment: I just tried to change the text of the labels and that works like a charm, each label gets the text changed so i must have the right connection, just wondering how on earth it can say it's a 0,0 frame.origin and center

Comment: I just uploaded a picture above, maybe it helps, but this really got me stunned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, it had to do with the fact that i was doing the whole thing in viewDidLoad, and i should be doing it in viewDidAppear. it must be because on viewDidLoad, it hasn't been placed yet, and therefore i could still change the text, coz the object label was created, but i couldnt get the origin coz it was not placed yet.

thanks for helping lads.

Comment: Or in `awakeFromNib`. The objects just are not "there" until the view loads. Which happens after `viewWillAppear` and before `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the view has a superview. The value depends on the superview's coordinates.

Comment: I added the view to the main views background in the storyboard editor, they should have a superview, or else they couldn't be added to the screen, could they?

Comment: Although, i did convert it to be a subclass of UIController instead of UIView, maybe this messes it up?

Comment: Just changed it back to being a UIView, still the same problem

Comment: @user1012558 ok - it's possible that 0 is the correct value, even more likely if the area is 0

Comment: i have 4 labels each located differently and each is 0

Answer (score 0):

You remove the constraints then run the app may be constraint create the problem because new xcode constraints create problem on some functions and properties so first remove the constraints by uncheck the "Use autlayout "then you check the app